# Dealing with intermittent Winsock errors

Tags: winsock

My client app gets intermittent winsock errors (10060, 10053) against one particular server we interface with.  I have it re-trying the request that failed, but sometimes it fails repeatedly, and I give up after 5 re-tries.  Would it be likely to help at all if I closed the socket and created a new one?  (I know nothing about the server-side.)

Comment: IMHO it doesn't do anyone any good to quote JUST the error numbers, I don't know them off by heart and I often can't be bothered to look them up for you. Why not start by looking up the errors in <winerror.h> and giving the #define name rather than simply the number. At least then people would have some idea of what errors your program is encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the errors that you're getting are:

```
10060 - WSAETIMEDOUT
10053 - WSAECONNABORTED
```

When do you get them? What are you doing at the time?

You get a `WSAECONNABORTED` when the remote end of the connection, or possibly an intermediary router, resets the connection and sends an RST. This could simply be the remote end issuing a non lingering close or it could be the remote end aborting or crashing.

You can't continue doing anything with a connection that has had a `WSAECONNABORTED` on it as the connection has been aborted and is no more; it is a dead connection, it has passed on...

Context matters immensely as to why you might get a `WSAETIMEDOUT` exception and the context will dictate if retrying is sensible or not.

Comment: I don't see how the context would matter, but it is a database search request.  Sometimes it'll work fine, sometimes it will time out.  When I re-try, I get a new connection, but I'm using the same socket as before.  The re-try often works, but sometimes it'll keep on failing.

Comment: No, the context as in which Winsock call you made which is giving the error and how the socket itself is set up.

Comment: m_socket = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

Comment: Oops it only let me edit the comment after I accidentally hit "return" for 5 minutes...
m_socket = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
WSAAsyncSelect(m_socket, m_hWnd, WM_SOCKET_EVENT, FD_CONNECT|FD_READ|FD_CLOSE|FD_WRITE);
...connect(m_socket, &m_sockAddr, sizeof(m_sockAddr);...
send(m_socket, pszMessage, cbMessage, 0);...
recv(m_socket, pszBuffer, m_nSize, 0);...
Sometimes it gets an FD_CLOSE error 10053 after receiving data, other times an FD_CONNECT error 10060 when trying a new request.

Comment: Well the timeout from the connect is likely to be either that there's a dns problem and the name resolution is timing out, OR the remote host is unreachable and an attempt to connect is timing out. I explained the `WSAECONNABORTED` result in the body of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would try is- do tracert to your server.

Often when someone is connected through VPN; you may see this error because your local and remote ip addresses overlap.

e.g. if your local ipaddress range is 192.168.1.xxx and vpn remote range is also 192.168.1.xxx you will also see this error.

sharrajesh